# Rails ActiveRecord type constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following model in a rails App
`class Banking::PaymentToken < Banking::Token (which is ActiveRecord)`

Banking::PaymentToken.find() include the following SQL constraint?

`"WHERE payment_tokens.type IN ('Banking::PaymentToken')"`

I want to add constraints `"WHERE payment_tokens.type IN ('Banking::PaymentToken', 'other_type')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats how ActiveRecord implements inheritance.

`Banking::Token < ActiveRecord::Base` is the base class working against payment_tokens table (all records). Which means any select from BankingToken will filter against all the records in payment_tokens table.

`Banking::PaymentToken < Banking::Token` inherits from `Banking::Token` which means it works against the same table but filters by default only `type = "Banking::PaymentToken"`,
(type is the default inheritance_column for Active Record)

You wish to create a new class which inherits from Banking::PaymentToken, lets say:
`Banking:OtherToken < Banking::PaymentToken`
As the mechanism works it will filter by default type in ("Banking:OtherToken").

Now `Banking::PaymentToken` filter by default will be: 
`type in ("Banking::PaymentToken", "Banking:OtherToken")` because every `OtherToken` is a `PaymentToken` as well..

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
Banking::PaymentToken.find_by(type: 'Banking::PaymentToken', 'other_type')
```

should be translated to the equivalent SQL you want.

Bear in mind  that `type` column is restricted word. Therefore, you have to know what you are doing when using this column name.

Comment: thanks for the reply, But I was think more about interfering in the model level so exiting Banking::PaymentToken.find will also find the other type.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:
I need to create the other part to inherit form PaymentToken
`Banking::OtherToken < Banking::PaymentToken`

That will give me the desired query.